# Vuelidate not showing the correct errors

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-material, vuelidate

I am new to vuelidate and while following some of the tutorial examples in their documentation i noticed the errors in my code were showing even before typing anything and the wrong errors are being shown, such as "minlenght" related error message showing before the "required field" error message.

Here's the [link](https://vuelidate.netlify.com/#sub-basic-form) for vuelidate documentation that i was following and here is the [link](https://vuematerial.io/components/form) to the official vue material form example i was following.

When i use the official vuelidate example the error message shows right of the bat instead of showing only after i type something:

[image]

Here is the single field form i was trying to implement the validation:

```
<template>
    <div class="action">
        <div class="md-layout md-gutter md-alignment-bottom-center ">
            <form novalidate class="md-layout" @submit.prevent="validateUser">
                <md-card class="cardStyle" >
                    <md-card-header>
                        <div class="md-title">FORM TEST</div>
                    </md-card-header>

                    <md-card-content>
                        FORM TYPE

                        <md-card class="md-medium-size-25 md-small-size-60 md-xsmall-size-100">
                            <md-card-expand>
                                <md-card-actions md-alignment="space-between">
                                    <div>
                                        INFO
                                    </div>

                                    <md-card-expand-trigger>
                                        <md-button class="md-icon-button">
                                            <md-icon>keyboard_arrow_down</md-icon>
                                        </md-button>
                                    </md-card-expand-trigger>
                                </md-card-actions>

                                <md-card-expand-content>
                                    <md-card-content>
                                        <md-field>
                                            <div>
                                                <label for="eventType">Event name</label>
                                                <md-input name="eventName" id="eventName" v-model="form.eventName"/>
                                            </div>
                                        </md-field>
                                            <span class="md-error" v-if="!$v.form.eventName.required">REQUIRED</span>
                                            <span class="md-error" v-else-if="!$v.form.eventName.minlength">INVALID</span>

                                    </md-card-content>
                                </md-card-expand-content>
                            </md-card-expand>
                        </md-card>
                    </md-card-content>
                </md-card>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<style  scoped>
    /*.cardStyle {
        min-width: 50%;
        margin: 4px;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
    }*/
    .action {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        position:sticky;
        padding-top: 5%;
        padding-bottom: 5%;
    }
</style>

<script>
    import { validationMixin } from 'vuelidate'
    import {
        required,
        email,
        minLength,
        maxLength
    } from 'vuelidate/lib/validators'

    export default {
        name: 'Budget',
        mixins: [validationMixin],
        data: () => ({
            form: {
                formType: null,
                eventName: null,
                BU: null,
                startDate: null,
                startHour: null,
                endDate: null,
                endHour: null,
                participants: null,
                coverage: null,
                local: null,

              },
        }),
        validations: {
          form: {
            eventName: {
              required,
              minLength: minLength(3)
            },
            lastName: {
              required,
              minLength: minLength(3)
            },
            age: {
              required,
              maxLength: maxLength(3)
            },
            gender: {
              required
            },
            email: {
              required,
              email
            }
          }
        },

    }
</script>
```

Comment: Assuming `.md-error` are error messages, i believe it should be `v-if="!$v.form.eventName.required"` instead of `v-if="$v.form.eventName.required"`

Comment: removing the "!" will just invert the situation and the error message wont appear initially but will be shown even when the field is validated.

Comment: i dont think you understood what i wrote

Comment: sorry, it is because the original code already had the "!" in it. Even with it added the errors still show up even before i type anything and when i do fill in the field the errors dont go away

Comment: ok then im not sure, if you could post runnable code i might be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Validate errors are visible right off the bat as you said. one way around it is to apply the lazy attribute to your v-model and use $v object as your model as shown below

```
<md-input name="eventName" id="eventName" v-model.lazy="$v.form.event.Name.$model"/>
```

Another thing you should do is to check for errors manually and display messages if errors exits

```
data() {
  return {
    hasError: false,
  };
},
methods: {
 submit() {
   if (this.$v.form.$pending || this.$v.form.$error) {
      this.hasError = true;
   }
 }
},
.....
```

when displaying errors you can now perform multiple checks

```
<span class="md-error" v-if="hasErrors && !$v.form.eventName.required">REQUIRED</span>
```